# Wordpress - widget save button break jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So, I have a widget. I can add div's after click through .append
When I add for example 5 divs and click save all of them dissapear. Also I can't add another divs. I need to reload wpadmin page then I can add it again.
I found something [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/executing-javascript-when-a-widget-is-added-in-the-backend/130136?noredirect=1#130136) but it seems to not working for me. Any ideas?

My js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


// basic add

$("button#remove").click(function(){
$(".marker").remove();
});


//add with position
var map = $(".map");
var pid = 0;

function AddPoint(x, y, maps) {

    var marker = $('<div class="marker"></div>');
    marker.css({
        "left": x,
        "top": y
    });
    marker.attr("id", "point-" + pid++);
    $(maps).append(marker);
    $('.marker').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var thisNew = $(this);

            var x = (ui.position.left / thisNew.parent().width()) * 100 + '%';
            var y = (ui.position.top / thisNew.parent().height()) * 100 + '%';

            thisNew.css('left', x);
            thisNew.css('top', y);

            console.log(x, y);
        }
    });
}
map.click(function (e) {
        var x = e.offsetX/ $(this).width() * 100 + '%';
        var y = e.offsetY/ $(this).height() * 100 + '%';
        AddPoint(x, y, this);
});

});
```